# Higher order voronoi diagram

Tags: c++, c, computational-geometry, cgal, voronoi

Are there any C/C++ libraries for building higher order voronoi diagrams? AFAIK, CGAL supports only ordinary voronoi diagrams.

Comment: Hi, aptypr, just quoting wikipedia here: "Although a normal Voronoi cell is defined as the set of points closest to a single point in S, an nth-order Voronoi cell is defined as the set of points having a particular set of n points in S as its n nearest neighbors. Higher-order Voronoi diagrams also subdivide space.
Higher-order Voronoi diagrams can be generated recursively. To generate the nth-order Voronoi diagram from set S, start with the (n − 1)th-order diagram and replace each cell generated by X = {x1, x2, ..., xn−1} with a Voronoi diagram generated on the set S − X."

Comment: Now I know nothing about voronoi diagrams, but that doesn't look too hard to accomplish if you know coding? Esp if each lower order voronoi diagram is generated for you by an OVD library

Answer (score 1):

Retrieving Voronoi cells from a Delaunay triangulation should work in any dimension, so CGAL's Delaunay_d class is probably a solution. But the computation times will rise considerably in higher dimensions.

Comment: I think he asked about Higher-Order Voronoi diagrams (i.e. the cells in a k-order Voronoi Diagram are defined by the k-closest points in the set), not the dimension of the space.

Answer (score 0):

As of CGAL 4.1, there is still no API for *k*-order Voronoi diagrams.  However, there is a demo in the [CGAL Ipelets package](http://www.cgal.org/Manual/latest/doc_html/cgal_manual/CGAL_ipelets/Chapter_main.html) that computes the dual *k*-order Delaunay triangulations.  You may find it useful as a starting point.

In the CGAL distribution, under the directory `demo/CGAL_ipelets`, look for the files `multi_delaunay.cpp` and `include/CGAL_ipelets/k_delaunay.h`.