# How to draw 2nd order Voronoi diagram in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, voronoi

The Matlab [function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/voronoi.html) voronoi(x,y) gives the first order Voronoi diagram for the set of points  $(x,y)$  e.g.

[image: example]

Can we use this function to draw a higher order such as 2nd order Voronoi diagram? By the order of a Voronoi diagram means the number of closest points. For example the regular Voronoi diagram is called first order because the cells have a single point that is closest to any place in the cell. A second order Voronoi diagram will have cells which are identified by the two closest points.

This previous question [Higher order voronoi diagram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12510575/higher-order-voronoi-diagram) discuss a similar problem but not in Matlab.

Comment: A quick search did not yield much. Perhaps this [File Exchange submission](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/43032-convert-voronoi-cells-to-region-mask/content/makelinefun.m) can help. Otherwise it should not be too hard to implement it given that you already have a function for the first order voronoi.

Comment: I am attempting to write on right now, for fun of course :)

Comment: note: writing it yourself is a bit more difficult than it seems.

Comment: @MZimmerman6 Are you attempting from the scratch or by using the first order voronoi(x,y) function from Matlab? and what is the pseudo-code you use?

Comment: I was writing it from scratch, but unfortunately things went down hill quickly. I wrote it from scratch for first order and it worked fine, but second order got kind of sketchy and was not accurate. I gave up for now. I am not entirely sure how you would use the first order to reach a higher order without really sitting there and thinking hard about it

Comment: @MZimmerman6 Would you like to share your code for first order please?

Comment: @MLT I will, let me clean some stuff up real quick. Also note, it just returns the plot, it does not return anything else. I was interested in the problem, but not THAT interested ;)

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin Do you know the relationship between first order and second order so that one can draw second order given the first order?

Answer (score 0):

IMO you can use the closest pair of the sites and a dendogram and the k-order voronoi is an overlay of x k-order voronoi but without  the intersecting edges.